# Cannot get site_credential.username in azurerm_app_service

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have got my app service:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "appservice" {

  name = name",
  location = "${var.location}",
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.resourcegroup.name}",
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan.id}"
    app_settings{
        ...
    }
    site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    scm_type                 = "LocalGit"
  }

}
```

And I try to add site_credential.username as a key_vault_secret

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "key_vault_secret_publish_profile_username" {
  name = "username"

  value = "${azurerm_app_service.appservice.site_credential.username}"
  vault_uri = "${azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.vault_uri}"
}
```

terraform plan is ok, when i try "terraform apply" it returns following error:

1 error(s) occurred:

- azurerm_key_vault_secret.key_vault_secret_publish_profile_username: Resource 'azurerm_app_service.appservice' does not have attribute 'site_credential.username' for variable 'azurerm_app_service.appservice.site_credential.username'

Terraform docs provides that scm_type must be set to "LocalGit" => https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "key_vault_secret_publish_profile_username" {
  name = "username"

  value = "${azurerm_app_service.appservice.site_credential.0.username}"
  vault_uri = "${azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.vault_uri}"
}
```